# no match for ‘operator<<’

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following code:

```
class A {
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, A &a);
};

A a() {
  return A{};
}

int main() {
  std::cout << a(); // error!
  //A aa = a(); std::cout << aa; // compiles just fine
}
```

It seems to me that the two lines in main should be equivalent but the compiler disagrees. The first line doesn't compile!

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘A’)
   std::cout << a();
             ^
...200 (!) more lines of stderr...
```

Why?

Comment: Try making the second argument a `const` reference.  You should have done that anyway to begin with.  You also should have posted more of the error message, as it should have clearly stated what the issue is.

Comment: You can bind a const reference to a temporary: e.g: `const int& = 7;` valid but you cannot bind a plain reference to a temprary or constant. (rvalue). e.g: `int& r = 7;` // error. Thus in your example the extraction operator takes a plain reference of class `A` thus you can only pass to it non-const lvalue reference. Since function that returns by value returns an rvalue thus your code fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to bind a temporary `A` instance to a non-const reference.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, A &a);
//..
A a() {
  return A{};
}
//...
std::cout << a(); // error. Binding a temporary to a non-const
```

The error, when compiled using g++, states this:

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'A&' to an rvalue of type 'A'
```

The solution is to make the parameter `const`:

```
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &a);
```